# Jw player videos are not playing on facebook timeline

Tags: facebook, video, embed, jwplayer

jwplayer videos are not playing on facebook timeline. I mentioned all meta tags perfectly.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.oncologytube.com/index.php?page=videos&section=view&vid_id=101217" />
<meta property="og:type" content="movie" /> 
<meta property="og:video:height" content="260" /> 
<meta property="og:video:width" content="420" /> 
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:title" content="OncologyTube - American Association for Cancer Research (AACR) 2011: William S.  Dalton, Ph.D., M.D." /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Dr. William S. Dalton, Moffitt Cancer Center's CEO, president and center director" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://img.youtube.com/vi/d2AfbyCdDb8/default.jpg" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.oncologytube.com/themes/oncology_tube/templates/source/pages/jwplayer/player.swf?file= http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com/v/d2AfbyCdDb8&autostart=true" />
```

facebook posts doesn't show play button. and showing up like just links.

and i was wondered some facebook users are seeing my posts as videos but i'm not.

can anyone help on this please?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I would update to 5.10 - http://www.longtailvideo.com/order/view, and also make sure that every tag from here is used - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/blog/19150/publish-your-videos-to-facebook-with-a-jw-player